# I'm an F1 visa holder in the United States trying to fill out a volunteer work sheet

Tags: visa

The form requires me to provide a Social Security Number, but I don't have one.  Also, I tried using my SEVIS ID displayed on the I20, but it won't accept that.

Comment: What sort of volunteering? If it is being asked because the organization does a background check?

Comment: Did you ask the people who gave you the form? What did they say?

Comment: Are you working on campus?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.